# How to update data in the Angular UI Grid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm trying to use the Angular UI Grid. In my HTML I have the following code.

```
    <div ui-grid="gridOptions"></div>
```

And in my controller I have the following javascript.

```
    $scope.values = [{ id: 0, namn: 'erik' }];

    $scope.gridOptions = {
                data: $scope.values
    }
```

When starting my page the data is displayed in the grid. The problem is when I try to update the data. The changes is not propragated to the grid.
The follwing will ***not*** update the grid. Why?

```
$scope.values = [{ id: 100, namn: 'Test' }];
```

Comment: when and how do you call the changing method?

Comment: For instance, if I call it in a click event.

Comment: please post more code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's rather somthing like this :

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
                data: 'values'
    }
```